# Trying to run script through crontab which won't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I'm having issues getting my crontab to run I have the following line added to my crontab -e but it won't start. The command runs fine if I run it manually.

```
0 */3 * * * cd /home/sam/p/ && /usr/bin/python3.5 start.py
```

Not getting any error messages and can't see the process when I run top or grep for it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens because the cron environment is different from your own.  Make sure your `start.py` script uses full paths to any referenced files or external scripts.  Make sure that your `start.py` script does not rely on environment variables that you have in your shell but it may not.  Try piping the cron output to a mail command so you can see what it is doing, like so:

```
0 */3 * * * cd /home/sam/p/ && /usr/bin/python3.5 start.py | mail -s "cron output" myself@example.com
```

Comment: No luck with that as I didn't get a mail. Can I set up my cron enviroment to function like shell does?

Comment: Try writing debugging output to a file in /tmp on the local system.  Compare the output of ```env``` in your shell to the output of the same command via your cron job.  Check the main system log file.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to troubleshoot this is to write a wrapper shell script and send the output to a log file.

1. Create file `python_start_cron.sh` with contents

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/sam/p/ && /usr/bin/python3.5 start.py
```

2. Set the execute bit on this script script and make sure the script works manually
3. Modify the cronjob as shown below

```
0 */3 * * * python_start_cron.sh >/tmp/python_start_cron.log 2>&1
```

After cron executes, check the contents of the log file to ascertain the cause of the problem.